# Does state object remain thes same instance while re-rendering and state setting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

let's suppose we have this useState variable:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({name: "Mark",isReal: "true"});
```

Every time my function component render, useState keeps saved the object.
But, it takes also the reference of the object?

Comment: @gazdagergo the question is not clear, but I think he's asking if the `state` value keeps the same object (reference) as long it will be replaced by another object via `setState`. If that was the question, the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

```
const [state, setState] = useState({name: "Mark",isReal: "true"});
```

`state` exposed from hook is stable until you update state using `setState`, no matter whether it is a complex or primitive value.

As you probably know best practice to update state is using previous state, and of course on update you must return "new" value. For example:

```
setState(prev => ({...prev, name: "Josh"});
```

As you see in state update you need to return new object (that is why we use spreading in newly created object) and it simply means new reference for `state`.

And regarding primitive values, if you update state with same(old) primitive value it will not cause element to rerender because value simply did not changed - when talking about primitives only value is important, not the reference as with complex types.

Comment: But there is a difference between objects and primitives. If you call `setState` with the same primitive value the component will not re-render. It will with the same `obj` (since they will have different reference)

Comment: Yes, I agree, if you update with same primitive value it will not rerender because value simply didnt changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you meant re-rendering the component or setting its state. Anyways I've created an example where you can test both.

If the parent component state changes (which means the child component gets **re-rendered**), the state object of the child **remains the same instance**.

If you call **setState** state though, it **creates a new instance** of course.

```js
// import { useState } from 'react' --> with babel import
const { useState } = React  // --> with inline script tag

const initialObject = {}

const Child = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialObject)
  
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log('child renders |', 'state object is', state === initialObject ? 'the same' : 'new')}
      <button onClick={() => setState({})}>Set child state</button>
    </div>
  )
}
  
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const [parentState, setParentState] = useState({})
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setParentState({})}>Set parent state</button>
      <Child />
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. You can test this by setting the state with an equal (by value) object. Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sameobjstatequestion-dvh9hd?file=/src/App.js)

```js
function App() {
  const [_, setObj] = useState({ a: 1 });

  console.log("rendered"); //This will be fired
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setObj({ a: 1 })}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```